# Using .js file within .mjs file NodeJS

Tags: node.js

I am more familiar using require() to load CommonJS files into my code. A library I am trying to use requires .mjs file so I am trying to get it to work. I thought it was relatively straight forward but I ran into an issue that I don't know what it is to even search it up.

In my GoogleHomeNotification.js file I have my app defined with 3 seperate functions. Within the same file

```
App.broadcast("Broadcasting a message");
```

or any other .js file I can use

```
const ax = require("../objects/GoogleHomeNotification.js");
ax.broadcast("Test");
```

Now in my test.mjs file I have

```
import * as GoogleNotification from "../objects/GoogleHomeNotification.js"
GoogleNotification.broadcast("Test");
```

and when I try to compile and run it, I get

`TypeError: GoogleNotification.broadcast is not a function.`

A nudge in the right direction of what I should be learning/searching for would be greatly appreciated!

GoogleHomeNotification.js:

```
var App = {
    playin: false,
    DeviceIp: "",
    OriginalVolume: .5,
    Player: null,
    GoogleHome: function (host, url, callback) {},
    run: function (ip, text) {},
    broadcast: function(text){}
};
module.exports = App;
```

EDIT: Node version 14.15.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```
import { default as GoogleNotification } from "../objects/GoogleHomeNotification.js";
```

Or if you dont need the alias, then just use

```
import App from "../objects/GoogleHomeNotification.js";
```

Comment: I don't need the alias for right now so the second option works, but I am curious as to why the original import didn't? Thank you by the way!

Comment: That is because when you use import * from... you import the whole module. 
Your export statement is equivalent to export default App;
So if you want, you should use it like this GoogleNotification.default.broadcast("message");